# Polygon attribute update by using line network

Tags: qgis, postgis

I've got a road polygon network and another line network that I pick some attributes from. In order to correctly update road polygons' attributes by using the line network, I use different kind of techniques like largest overlap join or picking the road name with the highest in count (for instance, there are seven pieces of lines intersect a polygon and 5 of them are road A and 2 are road B, and I select road A as the final name for that polygon).

So I've got an approach varying depending on the number of lines intersecting each polygon. As a result of that approach, I end up having an outcome I inevitable failed to correctly classify some polygons due to the vast irregularities in the shape of the polygons.

But I know (feel like) that correct classification of these remaining polygons is also doable with a one final run of fine tuning but I couldn't come up with a solution so far.

Is there an option (using QGIS, PostGIS) that I haven't considered so far?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried longest line length?

Comment: Yes, I did for some of them, but due the complexity I couldn't use it for all of them